# Sending an email when a thread completes in coldfusion

Tags: multithreading, email, coldfusion

So I have this ridiculously long process that calls a third party API, parses the data of over 3000 entries, and then either inserts or updates the data in our DB.

Right now, I have a link that when clicked will fire off an ajax request to the page that does all this processing. It returns JSON with the result of the processing (either an error or success message). The problem is, it takes about 15-20 mins for the processing to complete, and if the user closes the tab, it stops, or if they refresh the tab it starts over.

I have moved it to a thread so that it can run in the background and the user can move on without it stopping. But there is no way to return any error messages that might occur during the processing or when it completes. So I am trying to find a way to simply send an email to the admin when the thread completes.

I have the DB inserts and updates wrapped in try/catch blocks so that should handle any errors in the processing, but I need to find a way to send an email when the thread completes and the user has either moved away from the page, or even closed the browser.

I am not that familiar with coldfusion threads, and the documentation is ok, but not specific enough for my situation. any help here would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um, unless I'm crazy, why can't you just put the cfmail at the end of the thread? ie before the closing cfthread tag?

Comment: Turns out my thread is not actually running, which is why I am not getting the email when it completes. Thanks Ray.